# Trying to find the Duplicate value with Function but result shows empty

Tags: python

```
def Dupli(value):
    ref = []
    for number in value:
        if number not in ref:
            return ref.append(number)
        else:
            print(number)
            
eauid = [5,10,5,6,4,6]
Dupli(eauid)
```

Comment: a) Because your for-loop is immediately `return`ing the first time you do `return ref.append(number)`. b) Also because `ref.append(number)` doesn't have a return value. It appends-in-place and gives the value `None`. c) Solution is to declare an empty-list  `result = []`, and inside your loop apend to it. But only do `return result` outside the for-loop, after it has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is in the wrong place if you wanted your function to also return a list that didn't contain the duplicates. If you don't need a return value you can also remove the `return ref`.

```
def Dupli(value):
    ref = []
    for number in value:
        if number not in ref:
            ref.append(number)
        else:
            print(number)
    return ref


eauid = [5, 10, 5, 6, 4, 6]
Dupli(eauid)
```

output:

```
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zamil, if you want to append all the duplicate values and return the list then append the complete list and at last return it. The problem is that you are returning ref.append(number) which is returning None as the return type of append operation is None.

```
def Dupli(value):
  ref = []
  for number in value:
      if number not in ref:
          ref.append(number)
      else:
          print(number)
  return ref
eauid = [5,10,5,6,4,6]
Dupli(eauid)
```

Please let me know in the comments if any further clarification is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you just use one backspace before return you will get right answer.
Apart from this you can also use below code for same problem thanks

```
eauid = [5, 10, 5, 6, 4, 6]
ref=[]
for i in eauid:
    if i not in ref:
        ref.append(i)
    else:
        print(i,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do something like this too

```
from collections import Counter

def Dupli(value):
    print([x for x, v in Counter(ls).items() if v > 1])

eauid = [5, 10, 5, 6, 4, 6]
Dupli(eauid)
```

or in a single line using `lambda` functions as

```
Dupli = lambda value: print([x for x, v in Counter(ls).items() if v > 1])

Dupli([5, 10, 5, 6, 4, 6])
```

however it's not recommended to print inside the **functions**, but just  `return` them and `print` later.

**Edited!** @[juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) thanks for your mention :)

*now it's wokring with **O(n)** instated of **O(n^2)**, and about the **lambda** functions yes there is a **E731** warning for it.(which may ignore E731 or just use the first solution).*

Comment: `[x for x in value if value.count(x) > 1]` don't use this algorithm, it is unnecessarily inefficient. Also, don't assign the results of a lambda expression to a name, that defeats it's only purpose, and is explicitly against PEP8 style guidelines